# Compare two columns and replace value in R

Tags: r, compare

I want to compare the values of two columns in R. If the damage free days (dfd) are bigger or the same as the total days column (TotalDays) then I want to replace the dfy value to Age (this is in days) - TotalDays.

I've seen different questions about this but nothing has seemed to work so far. I'd be really grateful if anyone could help!

```
Example columns:

dfy        TotalDays   age    
7305.00    2872.21     10261
2556.75    3001.43     10210
3215.31    2941.87     12931
```

Example of what I want to achieve:
(dfy is replaced with age - TotalDays)

```
dfy        TotalDays   age
7433.79    2872.21     10261
2556.75    3001.43     10210
9988.13    2941.87     12931
```

Reproducible code:

```
df <- data.frame(dfy=c(7305.00,2556.75,3215.31),
          TotalDays = c(2872.21, 3001.43, 2941.87), age = c(10261, 10210, 12931))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a logical `vector` and replace only those elements in 'dfy' that are TRUE for that `vector`.

```
i1 <- with(df, TotalDays < dfy)
df$dfy[i1] <- with(df, age[i1] - TotalDays[i1])
```

---

A faster option would be using `data.table` by assigning (`:=`) in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[TotalDays < dfy, dfy := age - TotalDays]
```